# tangle init file async

Tags: async, org-mode, tangle

I use this function for tangling my init.el file

```el
(defun tangle-init ()
    "If the current buffer is 'init.org' the code-blocks are tangled, and the tangled file is compiled."
    (when (equal (buffer-file-name) (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.org")))
      (let ((prog-mode-hook nil)) ;; Avoid running hooks when tangling.
        (org-babel-tangle-file buffer-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el") "emacs-lisp")
        (byte-compile-file (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el")))))
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'tangle-init)
```

That code works well but it take a lot of time. So I would like to execute this function with async librairie (https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async)

I tried something like this but doesn't work:

```el
(require 'async)
  (defun tangle-init-async ()
    "If the current buffer is 'init.org' the code-blocks are tangled, and the tangled file is compiled."
    (when (equal (buffer-file-name) (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.org")))
      (async-start
       (lambda ()
         (let ((prog-mode-hook nil)) ;; Avoid running hooks when tangling.
           (org-babel-tangle-file buffer-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el") "emacs-lisp")
           (byte-compile-file (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el")))))))
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'tangle-init-async)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution adapt from  https://github.com/bixuanzju/emacs.d/blob/master/emacs-init.org

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emacs-async/")
  (require 'async)
  (defun tangle-init-async ()
    "If the current buffer is 'emacs-init.org' the code-blocks are tangled."
    (when (equal (buffer-file-name) (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.org")))
      (async-start
       `(lambda ()
          (require 'org)
          (org-babel-tangle-file (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.org")) (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el") "emacs-lisp"))
          )
       (lambda (result)
         (byte-compile-file (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el")))
         (message "Tangled file compiled.")))))
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'tangle-init-async)
```

Thanks to bixuanzju (Jeremy Bi)